# Data Binding troube using XML serialization and BindingList<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-serialization

Hi I am new to WPF C# and I am converting winform application to WPF and I am having difficulty in data binding( I do not have good idea about binding).
I am getting the error message :

> Binding Expression Path error: Classes property not found on 'object' ' ' String' HashCode = "" target element is 'TextBlock'(Name =' '); Target property is Text(type 'string')

Please help. thanks

I am using XML file and storing a sequence which contains classes( list of string values, like rotate, drag), list of coordinate points and output value.this is my database class.

```
public class Database
    {
     public BindingList<string> Classes { get;  set; }
        public BindingList<Sequence> Samples { get;  set; }


        public Database()
        {
            Classes = new BindingList<string>();
            Samples = new BindingList<Sequence>();
        }

        public void Save(Stream stream)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BindingList<Sequence>));
            serializer.Serialize(stream, Samples);
        }


        public void Load(Stream stream)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BindingList<Sequence>));
            var samples = (BindingList<Sequence>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

            Classes.Clear();
            foreach (string label in samples.First().Classes)
            {
                Classes.Add(label);
                Console.WriteLine(" lets check out the classes ....." + label);
            }

            Samples.Clear();
            foreach (Sequence sample in samples)
            {
                sample.Classes = Classes;
                Samples.Add(sample);
                Console.WriteLine(" lets check out the samples ....." + sample);
            }
        }
}
}
```

Sequence is somethink like this---------------

```
Sequence sample = new Sequence()
            {
                Classes = Classes,
                SourcePath = sequence,
                Output = classIndex
            };
```

Now I have a combobox which take value from BindingList Classes and datagrid which take value from Sequence. XML file is

```
<Window x:Class="WpfLearnGUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="417" Width="608">

    <DockPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto" LastChildFill="True">

        <DataGrid 
            DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding }"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="73" 
            Name="gridSamples"  Width="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  DockPanel.Dock="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="True">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                  Header="Gesture" />
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Class" 
                   />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>

        <Grid Height="Auto" Name="grid1" Background="Coral" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Width="Auto" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="240*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="264*" />

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                 <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,0,0,0" Name="cbClasses" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  DisplayMemberPath="Classes" SelectedValuePath="Classes" IsEditable="True" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />

            <Button Content="DataBase" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,1,0,0" 
                    Name="button5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" >
                <Button.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <Menu>
                            <MenuItem Header="_Open" IsCheckable="True" Click="Open_click"></MenuItem>
                        </Menu>
                    </ContextMenu>  
                </Button.ContextMenu>
                </Button>
        </Grid> 
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I am binding these two value in mainWindow like this.

```
database = new Database();
cbClasses.ItemsSource = database.Classes;
gridSamples.DataContext = database.Samples;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to take a step back and read some tutorials on WPF binding, specifically with  the concepts of:
* Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged
* MVVM pattern

I suggest you take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) which provides a very nice overview (with downloadable source code). You can also check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400583/how-to-set-different-horizontalalignment-to-listboxitems/15404164#15404164) to another question, which demonstrates some very basic data binding techniques.

Comment: Thank you. I know I need to learn about binding more in detail. But I figured out the problem. I needed to give the relative path in my item source binding and that solved my problem.